# Created new class Edit profile. Login works fine, but getting null pointer on verifyEditProfile()

Tags: selenium

```
public class EditProfile {
// public static WebDriver driver;

 //public TestLogin login;
// public static String baseURL = Configuration.testsite;
 TestLogin login = new TestLogin();
 public static WebDriver driver; 

@BeforeClass 
@Parameters("browser")
public void LoginToAnalytics() throws Exception{
    //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    login.setup("Firefox");
    login.testLogin();
}

analyticsLoginPage mylogin = PageFactory.initElements(driver, analyticsLoginPage.class);
```

********//Edit Progile test that fails******

```
@Test//(dependsOnMethods = { "testLogin" })
```

///******** Edit profile code

```
public void verifyEditProfile() throws InterruptedException {

*******//Getting null pointer here. Please help me understand why.///////

    analyticsLandingPage landingpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, analyticsLandingPage.class);
```

*******///This will work fine once it gets to this part

```
    analyticsEditProfilePage editprofile = PageFactory.initElements(driver, analyticsEditProfilePage.class);
```

*******waiting for page to load ///////////

```
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    landingpage.gotoProfile();

    /////This part is not running because of the error***////

    editprofile.verifyEditFirstName();

}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Is it because you've commented out the definition of `driver`? It's really hard to tell since we can't tell which bits of your code are commented for the purposes of this question and which bits are commented out "for real".

Comment: I tried to edit it to make it more readable but I couldn't make enough sense of it. The code as-is cannot compile and I can't tell where one piece ends and the next begins.

Comment: Your question and sample code are unclear. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on asking [good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: All good advices. Thanks Paul!

Answer (score 0):

You are not initiated driver, it is null

```
 public static WebDriver driver;
```

you may think starting firefox driver as below, but is it returning the driver?

```
  login.setup("Firefox");
```

Change this setup method to return driver and assign this to above static webdriver driver;

```
   driver= login.setup("Firefox");
```

Thank you,
Murali

Comment: Thanks Murali, COuld you give me an example of what you mean "Change this setup method to return driver and assign this to above static webdriver driver". I'm new to this. Appreciate your help!